# Сбой приложения размещенного в AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore, xcode7, ios8

Произошло один сбой приложения в размещенного AppStore. Как понять причину сбоя исходя из crash information. 
Сбой произошел на iPhone 4S с iOS 8.3 (12F70).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Развернул недостающие позиции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас на картинке шаги между 6 и 16 не показаны. можете развернуть и запостить картинку со всеми шагами

Comment: max-mikheyenko, развернуты все позиции. Больше ничего не разворачивается)

Comment: ну значит между 6м и 16м шагами приложение уходит в черную дыру. Внизу должна быть кнопка "show only stack trace with debug symbols" я думаю она вам нужна

Comment: Max Mikheyenko, спасибо за помощь, добавил картинку со всеми шагами.

Answer (score 1):

Вылет произошёл при выборе ячейки таблицы, большей информации из данного лога не получить.